# Few questions on complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

Hey few statements (correct / not correct) I'm not sure about.

1. If $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex numbers so that $z_1 + z_2$ and $z_1 z_2$ is a negative real number then $z_1$ and $z_2$ are real numbers. This statement has to be correct right?

$$\begin{align} |z+2|&=|z-1| \\ \sqrt{(x+2)^2 +y^2}&=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2} \\ x^2+4x+4+y^2&=x^2-2x+1+y^2 \\4x+4 &= -2x+1 \\
6x&=-3 \\
x&=-1/2\end{align}$$
nice thanks!

1. Term $|z+2|=|z-1|$ defines a line in complex plane. I have a problem visualizing this. I get the $|z+z_0|=R$ is $z_0$ centered circle with $R$ radius. Is this two circles with an intersection?

Comment: Let $z_1=a+bi$, $z_2=c+di$. Assume $b\neq 0$. Then $z_1+z_2$ is real if $d+b=0$, and $z_1z_2$ is real, if $a=c$. Now $z_1z_2=a^2+b^2<0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, they must be real, but it's not trivial! Hint: think quadratic equation.
2. This describes the set of points *equidistant* from some pair of points (in this case, $-2$ and $1$) - do you see why? The set of points equidistant from a pair of points forms a line.

Comment: 2.[like this?](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Perpendicular_bisector.gif) so it's a line going through the imaginary axis from 1 to -2.

Comment: @ELEC Right, it's the line of the form $-1/2+ix$ as $x$ varies. You can see this algebraically, too.

Comment: Can you give a hint on how does one see this algebraically. Why there is a displacement of $-1/2$ on the $x$-axis?

Comment: That's the average of $1$ and $-2$. For the hint: solve $|x+iy+2|=|x+iy-1|$.

Comment: Tried to solve on my OG post (edited) but still can't figure it out... sorry must be frustrating to try explaining this..

Comment: $|x+iy|^2=x^2+y^2$. Try using that! And no worries - but I've gotta go, so good luck.

Comment: Got it Thanks! I think I solved it on my original post correctly.